# Issue number missing from Bibliography in "model5-names" bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, elsarticle, custom-bib

Can someone help me with editing the bst file in order to make issue number appear in the bibliography. Example:

This:

Olivers, C. N. L., & Watson, D. G. (2008). Subitizing requires attention. *Visual Cognition, 16*, 439–462.

To this:

Olivers, C. N. L., & Watson, D. G. (2008). Subitizing requires attention. *Visual Cognition, 16*(11), 439–462.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use? It's the bibliography style that determines *if* (and if the answer is "yes", *how*) the issue number of a journal article is shown.

Comment: I forgot to mention — thank you Mico. The name of the style is model5-names.bst or APA style (original title, as in the downloaded template from Elsevier).

Comment: If you're supposed to use the `elsarticle` document class and the `model5-names` bibliography style for some journal submission, I don't think the editors would look kindly on any attempts to modify the bibliography style.

Comment: In my case that is true for revised submissions. Author guidelines discriminates between new and revised submissions. For new submissions: "There are no strict requirements on reference formatting at submission. References can be in any style or format as long as the style is consistent." Hence, I think it will be OK (I'm submitting new manuscript) .

Comment: If the activity is for a new submission, I don't understand why you would even bother thinking about modifying `model5-numbers.bst`. Under the remarks section of the upload-to-journal process, just provide a sentence or two about the bibliogrraphy style you used. Since `model5-names` is one of Elsevier's own "house styles", nobody should get bent out of shape.

Comment: As a temporary hack, you could change the volume field from `16` to `16\textup{(11)}`.

Comment: I get your point Mico, but the perfectionist in me is screaming :). I gotta have the style right. The developers of `model5-numbers.bst` should correct it, since it is referred to as "APA style" in the template, but actually is missing this information. Should be corrected on their side. Also, the hack you propose is clever, but I have a lot of cited works, can't change one by one... I wish someone could help me out with the bst file...

Comment: I've gone ahead and posted an answer. Happy BibTeXing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the journal's issue number to show up between the contents of the `volume` and `pages` fields, you will need to edit the bst (bibliography style) file as follows:

- Find the file `model5-names.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `mymodel5.bst`. (Don't edit the file `model5-names.bst` directly.)
- Open the file `mymodel5.bst` in a text editor; the editor you use for your tex files will do fine.
- Locate the function `format.vol.num.pages` in the file. (In my copy of the file, the function starts on line 875.)
- Insert the following code block between the lines that say `emphasize` and `format.journal.pages`:

  ```
    number empty$
      'skip$
      { "(" number * ")" * * }
    if$
  ```

  Even if you're not familiar with BibTeX's infix notation, you can probably guess what this code does: It checks if the `number` field is empty; if it's not, BibTeX inserts the contents of the `number` field, encased in parentheses.
- Save the file `mymodel5.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- Start using the new bibliography style by replacing the instruction `\bibliographystyle{model5-names}` with `\bibliographystyle{mymodel5}`. Run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!