# Get issue numbers for article in parentheses () for bibtex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

I have a format of the bibliography for my thesis that I like and slightly customized. The problem is issue numbers are not included and I need to add them into the style format. The relevant function I believe is `format.vol.num.pages` but not sure how to add them in parentheses and have them ignored if they aren't included as is the case for some journals.

The image is an example of the current format which can also be seen if you compile the `mwe.tex` with `MyStyle-Reduced.bst`. I want it to instead be **8**(2), so (2) is the issue number of the journal (2 is the number entry in the bibtex file). For the mwe, this would be **446**(1).

[image: Current citation format]

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
  bolden
  format.journal.pages
}
```

I have also added this function and tried including it into `format.vol.num.pages` but couldn't get it to work correctly. It would either remove the volume number of the journal or other incorrect things with whatever I tried:

```
FUNCTION {format.number}
{ number empty$
{ "" }
{ "(" number * ")"}
if$
}
```

Minimal working example of `mwe.tex` below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final,ocgcolorlinks=true,linktocpage,pagebackref,
hyperindex=true,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
\ifcase #1 %
(Not cited.)%
\or
(Cited on page~#2.)%
\else
(Cited on pages~#2.)%
\fi}
\usepackage[square,sort]{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{;}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Knu86,
author = {Qin, Michael K. and Oxenham, Andrew J.},
journal = {The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America},
number = {1},
pages = {446},
title = {{Effects of simulated cochlear-implant
processing on speech reception in fluctuating maskers}},
volume = {114},
year = {2003},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

This is test document with a reference \citep{Knu86}.

\bibliographystyle{MyStyle-Reduced.bst}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I have reduced the bibliography style down as far as I can but not sure how to reduce it anymore as part of the problem is I don't know much about how to edit `.bst` files. It is below `MyStyle-Reduced.bst`:

```
ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    url
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label extra.label sort.label short.list }
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }
FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}
STRINGS { s t}
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {add.blank}
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {date.block}
{
  new.sentence
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {non.stop}
{ duplicate$
   "}" * add.period$
   #-1 #1 substring$ "." =
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}
FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\textbf{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {tie.or.space.prefix}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$
}

FUNCTION {capitalize}
{ "u" change.case$ "t" change.case$ }

FUNCTION {space.word}
{ " " swap$ * " " * }
 % Here are the language-specific definitions for explicit words.
 % Each function has a name bbl.xxx where xxx is the English word.
 % The language selected here is ENGLISH
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}

FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editors}
{ "eds." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editor}
{ "ed." }

FUNCTION {bbl.edby}
{ "edited by" }

FUNCTION {bbl.edition}
{ "edition" }

FUNCTION {bbl.volume}
{ "volume" }

FUNCTION {bbl.of}
{ "of" }

FUNCTION {bbl.number}
{ "number" }

FUNCTION {bbl.nr}
{ "no." }

FUNCTION {bbl.in}
{ "in" }

FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "" }

FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "" }

FUNCTION {bbl.chapter}
{ "chapter" }

FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}
{ "Technical Report" }

FUNCTION {bbl.mthesis}
{ "Master's thesis" }

FUNCTION {bbl.phdthesis}
{ "Ph.D. thesis" }

MACRO {jan} {"January"}

MACRO {feb} {"February"}

MACRO {mar} {"March"}

MACRO {apr} {"April"}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"June"}

MACRO {jul} {"July"}

MACRO {aug} {"August"}

MACRO {sep} {"September"}

MACRO {oct} {"October"}

MACRO {nov} {"November"}

MACRO {dec} {"December"}

FUNCTION {bibinfo.check}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      pop$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ pop$
        }
        { swap$
          "\bibinfo{" swap$ * "}{" * swap$ * "}" *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.warn}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      swap$ "missing " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ "empty " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$
        }
        { swap$
          "\bibinfo{" swap$ * "}{" * swap$ * "}" *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    { "\urlprefix\url{" url * "}" * }
  if$
}

STRINGS  { bibinfo}
INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{ f{.}.}{ jj}"
%     The below used to get no periods and no spaces
%      "{vv~}{ll}{ f{}}{ jj}"
%     My original one with dots and space between
%      "{ll~}{vv~}{f.}{~jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal emphasize *
                }
                {
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{
  'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {

                  " " * bbl.etal emphasize *
                }
                {
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.key}
{ empty$
    { key field.or.null }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author "author" format.names
}
FUNCTION {get.bbl.editor}
{ editor num.names$ #1 > 'bbl.editors 'bbl.editor if$ }

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor "editor" format.names duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "," *
      " " *
      get.bbl.editor
      *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.note}
{
 note empty$
    { "" }
    { note #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "{" =
        'skip$
        { output.state mid.sentence =
          { "l" }
          { "u" }
        if$
        change.case$
        }
      if$
      note #2 global.max$ substring$ * "note" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { "t" change.case$ }
  if$
  "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "\enquote{" swap$ *
%      ".} " *
      "} " *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {end.quote.title}
{ title empty$
    'skip$
    { before.all 'output.state := }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.full.names}
{'s :=
 "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal emphasize *
                }
                {
                  numnames #2 >
                    { "," * }
                    'skip$
                  if$
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.full}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.full.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.full}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.full}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {make.full.names}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.full
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.full
        'author.key.full
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[{" write$
  label write$
  ")" make.full.names duplicate$ short.list =
     { pop$ }
     { * }
   if$
  "}]{" * write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{
  't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {word.in}
{ bbl.in
  " " * }

FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    {
      "empty year in " cite$ * "; set to ????" * warning$
       pop$ "????"
    }
    'skip$
  if$
  bolden
  extra.label *
  before.all 'output.state :=
  " (" swap$ * ")" *
}
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      emphasize
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.prefix
      "volume" bibinfo.check * *
      series "series" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        { swap$ bbl.of space.word * swap$
          emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { series empty$
            { number "number" bibinfo.check }
        { output.state mid.sentence =
            { bbl.number }
            { bbl.number capitalize }
          if$
          number tie.or.space.prefix "number" bibinfo.check * *
          bbl.in space.word *
          series "series" bibinfo.check *
        }
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      output.state mid.sentence =
        { "l" }
        { "t" }
      if$ change.case$
      "edition" bibinfo.check
      " " * bbl.edition *
    }
  if$
}
INTEGERS { multiresult }
FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { duplicate$ multi.page.check
        {
          n.dashify
        }
        {
        }
      if$
      "pages" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ pop$ format.pages }
        {
          ", " *
          swap$
          n.dashify
          "pages" bibinfo.check
          *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.number}
{ number empty$
    { "" }
    { "" number * }
  if$
%  before.all 'output.state :=
%  "(" swap$ * ")" *
}

FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
  bolden
  format.journal.pages
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
        { bbl.chapter }
        { type "l" change.case$
          "type" bibinfo.check
        }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.prefix
      "chapter" bibinfo.check
      * *
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.booktitle}
{
  booktitle "booktitle" bibinfo.check
  emphasize
}
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      editor "editor" format.names.ed duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        {
          bbl.edby
          " " * swap$ *
          swap$
          "," *
          " " * swap$
          * }
      if$
      word.in swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    { swap$ pop$
      "t" change.case$ "type" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ number "number" bibinfo.check
  type duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ bbl.techrep }
    'skip$
  if$
  "type" bibinfo.check
  swap$ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "t" change.case$ }
    { tie.or.space.prefix * * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{
  word.in
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      pop$ word.in
    }
    { bbl.volume
      swap$ tie.or.space.prefix "volume" bibinfo.check * * bbl.of space.word *
    }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{
  word.in
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
  ""
  address empty$ t empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      add.blank "(" *
      t empty$
        { address "address" bibinfo.check *
        }
        { t *
          address empty$
            'skip$
            { ", " * address "address" bibinfo.check * }
          if$
        }
      if$
      ")" *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {format.organization.address}
{ organization "organization" bibinfo.check format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  end.quote.title
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal
      "journal" bibinfo.check
      "journal" output.check
      add.blank
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  %format.url output
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }
READ
FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
  "l" change.case$
}
INTEGERS { len }
FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  "" 't :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$
      " " * bbl.etal emphasize *
    }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            {
              " " * bbl.etal emphasize *
            }
            { bbl.and space.word * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
              * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.label}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.lab.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.label}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.lab.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {calc.short.authors}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.label
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.label
        'author.key.label
      if$
    }
  if$
  'short.list :=
}

FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ calc.short.authors
  short.list
  "("
  *
  year duplicate$ empty$
  short.list key field.or.null = or
     { pop$ "" }
     'skip$
  if$
  *
  'label :=
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  ""
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  f{ }}{  jj{ }}"
      format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          "   "  *
          namesleft #1 = t "others" = and
            { "zzzzz" * }
            { t sortify * }
          if$
        }
        { t sortify * }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
  "A " #2
    "An " #3
      "The " #4 t chop.word
    chop.word
  chop.word
  sortify
  #1 global.max$ substring$
}
FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
              ""
            }
            { key sortify }
          if$
        }
        { editor sort.format.names }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {editor.sort}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need editor or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
  label sortify
  "    "
  *
  type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.sort
        'author.sort
      if$
    }
  if$
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.label :=
  sort.label
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}

ITERATE {presort}
SORT
STRINGS { last.label next.extra }
INTEGERS { last.extra.num number.label }
FUNCTION {initialize.extra.label.stuff}
{ #0 int.to.chr$ 'last.label :=
  "" 'next.extra :=
  #0 'last.extra.num :=
  #0 'number.label :=
}
FUNCTION {forward.pass}
{ last.label label =
    { last.extra.num #1 + 'last.extra.num :=
      last.extra.num int.to.chr$ 'extra.label :=
    }
    { "a" chr.to.int$ 'last.extra.num :=
      "" 'extra.label :=
      label 'last.label :=
    }
  if$
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
}
FUNCTION {reverse.pass}
{ next.extra "b" =
    { "a" 'extra.label := }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label 'next.extra :=
  extra.label
  duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    { "{\natexlab{" swap$ * "}}" * }
  if$
  'extra.label :=
  label extra.label * 'label :=
}
EXECUTE {initialize.extra.label.stuff}
ITERATE {forward.pass}
REVERSE {reverse.pass}
FUNCTION {bib.sort.order}
{ sort.label
  "    "
  *
  year field.or.null sortify
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}
ITERATE {bib.sort.order}
SORT
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{" number.label int.to.str$ * "}" *
  write$ newline$
  "\newcommand{\enquote}[1]{``#1''}"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname url\endcsname\relax"
  write$ newline$
  "  \def\url#1{\texttt{#1}}\fi"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname urlprefix\endcsname\relax\def\urlprefix{URL }\fi"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\switchargs}[2]{#2#1}"
  write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {begin.bib}
EXECUTE {init.state.consts}
ITERATE {call.type$}
FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {end.bib}
%% End of customized bst file
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I have added a mwe.tex file and I have removed as much from the `MyStyle-Reduced.bst` as I could but it is still quite long. This is the file that needs modified. I want it to use the issue number (number bibtex entry) and place it after the volume in parantheses (). Let me know if any other information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the `format.number` function below and modified the `format.vol.num.pages` as shown to call `format.number` after `bolden`. P.S. I mainly realized the tip from this post: [Link to help understand getting issue numbers in parantheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270225/issue-number-missing-from-bibliography-in-model5-names-bibliography-style)

```
FUNCTION {format.number}
    {number empty$
        'skip$
        { "(" number * ")" * * }
      if$
    }


FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
  bolden
  format.number
  format.journal.pages
}
```